# .NET Core Rabbitmq read messages one by one

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

I want to run a message queuing system in my .NET Core project. I use rabbitmq for this.

The producer section works fine and I can see the messages in a single queue. There is a different situation in the consume part. When I interrupt the running status of the project I created for consume, in addition to deleting the messages it has processed, it also deletes the ones it has not processed, and the queue is completely emptied.

How do I prevent it from deleting messages it's not processing, or make it only work for one message and then move on to the next message?

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory
    {
        HostName = "localhost",
        UserName = "user",
        Password = "pass",
        VirtualHost = "/"
    };

    factory.Uri = new Uri("uri:uri/uri");

    using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

    channel.QueueDeclare("personels", durable: true, exclusive: false);

    channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

    consumer.Received += (sender, e) =>
    {
        ProcessMessage(e);

        channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
    };

    channel.BasicConsume("personels", false, consumer);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void ProcessMessage(BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
{
    var body = e.Body;
    var encoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.Span);
    List<Personel> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Personel>>(encoded);

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=test;User ID =test/test;Password=;TrustServerCertificate=True;Initial Catalog=Example;Integrated Security=True;");
    connection.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < response.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = response[i];

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("Insert Into BAR (Name, Description) Values");
        stringBuilder.Append($"('{item.Name}', '{item.Description}')");

        string query = stringBuilder.ToString();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{i} - added..");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay i fixed it with this : 
`channel.QueueDeclare("personels", durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete : false);`